# element.scrollLeft weird values

Tags: javascript, scroll

i'm getting different scroll position values on Google chrome browser.
on desktop browser the `element.scrollLeft` starts with `0` and ends with `500`,
on mobile browser it starts with `-500` and ends with `0`

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome on mobile requires "minimum-scale=1" on the viewport meta.

`<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1">`

It should work.